# Object moving on it's own when rendered!

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, transforms

Sometime when I move an object in the viewport it renders ok in the real-time rendered viewport (Cycles) but as soon as I press F12 and render the image - it goes back to the original location in the rendering as well as the viewport. It doesn't happen all the time but I have faced this issue few times in the past couple of months.

I have a feeling that it's something to do with the parenting. But I have tried everything I could think of - un-parenting, re-parenting with or without keeping transform but nothing seem to help!

Here is a screen capture of the issue:
[image: BLender Object Moving When rendered!]

Here is the .blend file in case anyone wants to examine it:
http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=47962

Could anyone suggest what's the issue and how to avoid it?

Comment: watch your timeline remove all the keyframe from the timeline and render

Comment: This is a shallow problem, encountered by countless Users. You will conquer this. Please know this ... Keyframes dominate temporary movements which are [not] keyframes.    Move your timeline to previous and next frames to verify the render positions. You will see temporary positions disappear. Do not depend on temporary positions.  When the Blender User inserts a keyframe the permanent change is made.  At least in this example.  For simple positions two keyframes determine every frame position between them.  Learn how to insert keyframes.  See a tutorial on youtube or search here at BSE.

Comment: atomicbezierslinger: Thank you for the reply. Only the empty (parent) has keyframe but not the torus - still it's jumping back to its original location - that's why I am getting confused.
Thanks for moving timeline tip. I will try it next time.

Comment: please next time use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to share .blend files, then edit your question and paste the provided link...

Comment: the "trs" object has an action (_breeze packaging_main deviceAction.001) and is parented to the "animated_empty" which has an action too (EmptyAction.003)

Comment: Post it as an answer, @atomicbezierslinger

Comment: @m.ardito Thanks for your reply and examining the scene. Thanks for pointing it out the action. I will post this as the answer. Really appreciate your help.
How is blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com better than http://pasteall.org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have looked at the Graph Editor and the Dope Sheet - after deleting the unwanted keyframes the problem is resolved. 
[image: Check the graph editor and dopes heet to resolve the issue]

Thanks **atomicbezierslinge** and **m.ardito** for pointing the issue with keyframes.